# How can I make a file visible both when project is deployed on a server and when its classes are run from test classes?

Tags: java, maven, path, jboss

If I use a file calling it directly:

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("SR02_pattern.xls");
```

( the file is in \apv\main-app directory), it won't be deployed, and of course, it won't be seen when the project will be run on the server.

If I put the file in the /apv/main-web/WEB-INF/classes/ directory, it will be deployed and I can call it by

```
InputStream inStream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("SR02_pattern.xls")
```

when the project is deployed on the server, but that line won't read the file in the case the class was run from the test.

Probably, the place where the file will be looked for by getResourceAsStream("SR02_pattern.xls"), is set by some system properties and I can use them, but I don't know which properties can help.

How can I read the file in both cases by the same code without passing it as a parameter into the class?

There are many answers on SO for either of those cases, but I couldn't find one that works for both. The default paths for both cases are different.

Of course, I can put the file in both places, and in case the file is not in the first folder, look it in the second, as I am doing now, but upkeeping two copies is prone to errors and I desire to use better style.

Comment: You should use `this.getClass().getResourcesAsStream('/SR02-pattern.xl')` for all parts in test as well in production code...The `/` defines the root directory for the resources

Comment: And where should the file be? Together with the java code of the file-using class?

Comment: The files should be located in `src/main/resources`...

Comment: And that folder will be deployed?

Comment: It will be part of the resulting war file ...in `WEB-INF/classes` ...

Comment: Oh! And so the same reading will work for both cases. Excellent. BTW, the test works already for the lines:             URL resource = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(EXCEL_PATTERN_NAME);
            File file = new File(resource.toURI());
            FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);   (I have to use FileInputStream  for further use by apache POI). Could you make an answer of that? I think it could be a very good answer, better than 40 current ones that work only in one case or at least say that.

Comment: The FileInputStream is an `InputStream` which is returned by `this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(..)` ...

Comment: getResourceAsStream does not returns FileInputStream, only InputStream. It should be translated somehow. There is another problem I had found: reading of the file from the war. But anyway, your comment gives correct address for both cases, I have checked it already, and I would gladly check and upvote it, so, please make an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream('/SR02-pattern.xl')` for all parts in test as well in production code. The `/` defines the root directory for the resources.

The files you would like to read should be located in `src/main/resources`. This will result in the final war package at the location `WEB-INF/classes`.

Comment: Sorry, I corrected the method name - it should be Resource, not Resources there.

Comment: From my side, I want to add that it really works, and points to correct folders in both cases of deployment in the server and running from the test. And you needn't copy the file, it will be copied where you need it, automatically.